# Who acts in Arendt's Human Condition?

Tags: political-philosophy, human-condition, arendt, action

In Hannah Arendt's The Human Condition, she categorises the active life as Labor, Work and Action where labor is performed by *animal laborans* and work by *homo faber*. To my knowledge, Arendt does not ascribe any particular name to the aspect of humans that performs actions.

Is there an appropriate name for the performer of actions, either from Arendt herself or from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Animal Laborans' and 'Homo Faber' are phrases Arendt took from the philosophical literature: the first from Marx, the second from less notable ancient Roman and middle ages Italian thinkers. The 'Vita Activa' is what Arendt is reaching for philosophically. It isn't simply a political class for her, but the essence of being fully and completely human. In that sense it's not an 'aspect' of human nature that can be used for classification purposes; it's the culmination of human nature.

Arendt is focused on the socio-psychological modes of Labor, Work, and Action. She wasn't particularly trying to find labels that fit the people who operate in those modes, so used ones she had ready to hand. If she'd been pressed for a Latinate term, I suspect she'd have used 'Homo Politicus' — at least, a number of people writing *about* Arendt's work use that phrase — but I don't know of any place in her work or interviews where that phrase came up.

Comment: -1: It's referred to as *Homo Politicus* by her commentators; which is justified by the first chapter of *The Human Condition* where she states "the special relationship between action and being seems to fully justify the early translation of Aristotle's *zoon politikon* by *animal socialisis* ..."

Comment: TW: query noted. Will check: GLT